# Websocket++ error: handle_transport_init received error: TLS handshake failed

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, websocket, websocket++

When I connected to localhost it worked. But when I'm trying connect to wss://echo.websocket.org it says:

[2020-07-03 00:24:19] [connect] Successful connection

[2020-07-03 00:24:20] [error] handle_transport_init received error: TLS handshake failed

[2020-07-03 00:24:20] [fail] WebSocket Connection 174.129.224.73:443 - "" / 0
websocketpp.transport.asio.socket:8 TLS handshake failed

[2020-07-03 00:24:20] [info] asio async_shutdown error: asio.ssl:336462231 (shutdown while in init)

What I need to do to make it works?

Parts of code:

```
typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_tls_client> client;

struct connection_data
{
    bool status;
    string error;
    
    vector <string> messages;

    client::connection_ptr con;
    websocketpp::lib::shared_ptr<websocketpp::lib::thread> m_thread;
};

struct connection_data m_con;
client cl;
```

```
using namespace std;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
using websocketpp::lib::bind;

typedef websocketpp::config::asio_client::message_type::ptr message_ptr;
typedef websocketpp::lib::shared_ptr<websocketpp::lib::asio::ssl::context> context_ptr; 

void on_message(client* c, websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, message_ptr msg)
{
    m_con.messages.push_back(msg->get_payload());
}

void on_open(client* c, websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl)
{
    m_con.status = true;
}

void on_close(client* c, websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl)
{
    m_con.status = false;
    m_con.con = c->get_con_from_hdl(hdl);
    m_con.messages.clear();
    m_con.error.clear();
}

context_ptr on_tls_init(const char* hostname, websocketpp::connection_hdl) {
    context_ptr ctx = websocketpp::lib::make_shared<boost::asio::ssl::context>(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv13);
    return ctx;
}

void on_http(client* c, websocketpp::http_handler hdl)
{
    
}

void run()
{
    cout << "Thread enter" << endl;
    cl.run();
}

DLL void websock_open(char* address)
{
    string uri = string(address);
    websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;
    try {
        cl.set_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all);
        cl.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all);
        
        cl.init_asio();

        // Setting callbacks
        cl.set_message_handler(bind(&on_message, &cl, ::_1, ::_2));
        cl.set_open_handler(bind(&on_open, &cl, ::_1));
        cl.set_close_handler(bind(&on_close, &cl, ::_1));
        cl.set_tls_init_handler(bind(&on_tls_init, string(address).c_str(), ::_1));
        
        m_con.con = cl.get_connection(uri, ec);
        if (ec) {
            m_con.error = "Can't connect: " + ec.message();
        }
        cl.connect(m_con.con);
        cout << "connected" << endl;
        m_con.m_thread = websocketpp::lib::make_shared<websocketpp::lib::thread>(&run);
        cout << "Thread created" << endl;
        m_con.status = true;
    } catch (websocketpp::exception const & e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this question. There was error with verifying certificates.
Code to fix it:

```
context_ptr on_tls_init(const char* hostname, websocketpp::connection_hdl) {
    context_ptr ctx = websocketpp::lib::make_shared<boost::asio::ssl::context>(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12);
    try {
        ctx->set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3 |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);


        ctx->set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none);
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        m_con.error = string(e.what());
    }
    return ctx;
}
```